# Google Calendar API: No event details due to service account access role

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps, service-accounts

I'm using a Google service account to authorize my app to the Calendar API to read calendar event data to determine if a user is busy or not. The problem is that because the `accessRole` of the service account is 'freeBusyReader', the API does not return the `eventType` parameter, which I need to process the business logic.

One thing I had to do was have users share their calendar with the service account, and I notice that in the sharing settings, only the 'See only free/busy' option is selectable, the rest are not. I can't select the 'See all event details' option which I believe would let me see the parameters I need from the API.

What are my options to move forward here? Ideally I don't want to have a Google Admin apply any calendar sharing options org-wide, so is there something I can change on the service account perhaps?

I really only need the `eventType` parameter from the API, but I believe it's because of the sharing/access role settings that I can't see it.

Comment: Forgive me if I’m missing something obvious, but doesn’t the easy answer to grant the service account a more privileged role a la `reader` seem like the right way to go?

Comment: @esqew How would I go about doing that? I don't see anywhere obvious in the Google Console to do that. Apologies, I'm new to using Google Cloud so I am not super familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the constraint that you do not want a Google Admin to apply calendar sharing options organization-wide, and considering the limitations you are facing with the service account's access role, I could see two options within these constraints:

1. **Investigate [service account delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en)**

   See if domain-wide delegation for the service account is feasible. That is a feature in Google Workspace that allows a service account to impersonate users in your domain.

   With this, the service account could access calendar details as if it were the user, bypassing the need for individual calendar sharing settings. However, this still might require some level of admin setup, but it is more targeted than changing sharing options org-wide.
2. **Or: Use OAuth 2.0 with user consent**

   Implementing an [OAuth 2.0 flow](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/security/oauth/oauth-introduction) for individual user consent remains another option. That approach does not rely on service accounts or admin-level changes.

   Each user would grant your application permission to access their calendar details, including the `eventType` parameter. That method is more user-centric.
   See "[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)":

   - Use Google's documentation to set up OAuth 2.0 in your application.
   - Redirect users to Google's OAuth 2.0 server for consent.
   - Handle the response and exchange the code for tokens.
   - Use the access token to call the Google Calendar API to access the eventType parameter and other details.

---

The [OP Arin Zandbergen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6872517/arin-zandbergen) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77648499/google-calendar-api-no-event-details-due-to-service-account-access-role/77663041#comment136962833_77663041) to "[Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Application / Preparing to make a delegated API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest)"

> I had already enabled domain-wide delegation and so, since I'm creating the JWT and HTTP request manually, I needed to add a '`sub`' parameter to the JWT which contained the email ID of the user I want to impersonate.
> Once that was done, I was getting the parameters I needed.

True: With domain-wide delegation enabled, the service account can act on behalf of users in the Google Workspace domain.
When creating the JSON Web Token (JWT) for authentication, include a '`sub`' (subject) field in the JWT payload. That 'sub' field should contain the email ID of the user you want to impersonate. By doing this, the service account can perform actions as if it were the impersonated user, thereby gaining access to detailed calendar information.

With the JWT set up correctly, you can then use it to authenticate HTTP requests to the Google Calendar API. That approach allows you to access the `eventType` parameter and other detailed information as the impersonated user.

```bash
+-------------------------+
|  Google Service         |
|  Account with           |
|  Domain-Wide Delegation |
|                         |
|  +-------------------+  |
|  | JWT with 'sub'    |  |
|  | for User          |  |
|  | Impersonation     |  |
|  +-------------------+  |
+-------------------------+
            |
            | Impersonating User
            v
+-------------------------+
|  User's Calendar        |
|                         |
|  - Full Event Details   |
|  - eventType Access     |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: I have domain wide delegation turned off for the service-account because I had read that this can give wider access to resources but I'm not sure how to amend my API call to leverage this. I'm doing this in a language that doesn't have any Google libraries, so I'm building the HTTP requests manually, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ArinZandbergen "I'm doing this in a language that doesn't have any Google libraries": OK... which language are you using then?

Comment: Salesforce Apex

Comment: @ArinZandbergen Thank you for the feedback. I will amend this answer tomorrow.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer as it lead me to what I needed to do. I had already enabled domain-wide delegation and so since I'm creating the JWT and HTTP request manually, I needed to add a 'sub' parameter to the JWT which contained the email ID of the user I want to impersonate. Once that was done, I was getting the parameters I needed. See here for reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest

Comment: @ArinZandbergen Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer to include your comment and some additional elements around your solution.